# Recursion within a thread

Tags: c, multithreading

Is it a good idea to call a recursive function  inside a thread ?
I am creating 10 threads, the thread function in turn call a recursive function . The bad part is

```
ThreadFunc( )
{
   for( ;condn   ;   )
     recursiveFunc(objectId);
}


bool recursiveFunc(objectId)
{
    //Get a instance  to the database connection

    // Query for attibutes of this objectId

    if ( attibutes satisfy some condition)
        return true;
    else
        recursiveFunc(objectId)   // thats the next level of objectId
}
```

The recursive function has some calls to the database 
My guess is that a call to recursive function inside a  loop is causing a performance degradation. Can anyone confirm

Comment: Can you give more information on what your recursive function is doing?

Answer (score 2):

Calling a function recursively inside a thread is not a bad idea per se. The only thing you have to be aware of is to limit the recursion depth, or you may produce a (wait for it...) stack overflow. This is not specific to multithreading but applies in any case where you use recursion.

In this case, I would recommend against recursion because it's not necessary. Your code is an example of [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion), which can always be replaced with a loop. This eliminates the stack overflow concern:

```
bool recursiveFunc(objectId)
{
    do
    {
        // Get an instance to the database connection

        // Query for attributes of this objectId

        // Update objectId if necessary (not sure what the "next level of objectId" is)
    }
    while(! attributes satisfy some condition);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no technical reason why this wouldn't work - it's perfectly legal.

Why is this code the "bad part"?

You'll need to debug/profile this and `recursiveFunc` to see where the performance degradation is.

Going by the code you've posted have you checked that `condn` is ever satisfied so that your loop terminates. If not it will loop for ever.

Also what does `recursiveFunc` actually do?

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment that each thread performs 15,000 iterations the first thing I'd do would be to move the `Get an instance to the database connection` code **outside** `recursiveFunc` so that you are only getting it once per thread.

Even if you rewrite into a loop (as per Martin B's answer) you would still want to do this.

Comment: When I call the recursive function after the for loop the performance is good

Comment: @sameer: In that case, have you investigated how many iterations the for loop performs? Your problem might lie there rather than with `recursiveFunc` itself.

Comment: @sameer: In that case -- probably stating the obvious -- whatever you're doing in "Query for attibutes of this objectId" is taking a long time. Can you show us code for this? Does it involve a database query? You certainly don't want to be doing 15,000 database queries in a loop... if that's what you're doing, think about how you can consolidate them into a single query.

Comment: @martin YEs that could be an approach ... but what puzzles me , why the performance degrades when I use multithread approach

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the recursive function talks to the database. If each (or many) level of recursion reopens the database that can be the reason for degradation. If they all share the same "connection" to the database the problem is not in recursion but in the number of threads concurrently accessing the database.

Comment: The database connection is shared across all the threads ...When I perform recursion in a single thread the performance is slightly better than the threaded approach

Answer (score 0):

The only potential problem I see with the posted code is that it can represent an infinite loop, and that's usually not what you want (so you'd have to force break somewhere on known reachable conditions to avoid having to abend the application in order to break out of the thread (and subsequently the thread).

Performance degradation can happen with both threading, recursion, and database access for a variety of reasons.
Whether any or all of them are at fault for your problems is impossible to ascertain from the little you're showing us.